# How can I set an action command to window closing event?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

How can I set an action command to closing event of a custom frame class which is a subclass of `javax.swing.JFrame`?

This is the current code:

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // some stuff here
  }
});
```

The code that goes in `// some stuff here` is shared with a button labeled `quit`. For the button, I have set an action command to `"quit"` and set the listener to an external class named `NavigationHandler` whose `actionPerformed` has a case for `"quit"`. If I could set the action command of my window closing event to `"quit"`, I could use the same listener for the window too.

Currently I have a method that I call from both sites, but that feels unclean.

Comment: You don't so much 'set an action command' as 'override the window closing behavior'.  See `WindowListener` for details.

Comment: OK.. now, seeing your edit makes me ask:  What are you actually trying to achieve here?  What is the application feature you wish to offer the end-user?

Comment: `set an action command` sorry BNI, that equals closing JFrame for example on `ESC` key from keyboard ???

Comment: What does `JButton` have to do with window listener?

Comment: *"Currently I have a method that I call from both sites, but that feels unclean."*  Seems fine to me.  My answer would be 'call that method from both places'.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, they share the same behavior.

Comment: @mKorbel, I did not understand your question. What's BNI?

Comment: `BNI == batteries not included`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as follow

**To reuse the actionListener of quite button you can click quite button in  windowClosing .**

to click a button from code call [doclick()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) method. [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CallbuttondoClickmethodtosimulateaclickaction.htm)

```
quitButton.doClick();
```

Comment: you can call the  quitButton.doClick(); in window closing event see the example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CallbuttondoClickmethodtosimulateaclickaction.htm

Comment: That's it! If you edit your answer with this suggestion, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the JFrame which will let you get close events.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new MyWindowListener());
...
public class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
      // do something
    }
}
```